# HttpRequest and reportProgress not working or messing up my requests

Tags: angular, file-upload, httprequest, angular-httpclient

I am implementing a file upload service with Angular 5 and I want to give the user some feedback on the upload progress. I found several pages suggesting to use the `reportProgress` parameter that comes with Angulars `HttpClient`, but I cannot get it working.

I use a wrapper class for all my http-requests, which then does some logic and finally all requests end up in the same method that's being called:

```
public request(request: HttpRequest<any>, options?: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.request(request.method, request.url, {
    body: request.body,
    headers: request.headers,
    responseType: request.responseType,
    ...options
  });
}
```

I then pass a upload (post) call to it, with `{ reportProgress: true }` as `options`. This did not work at all, nothing on the request changed. So I suspected, that I actually need to use the `reportProgress`-parameter in the HttpRequest constructor to make it work and changed my code accordingly:

```
public request(request: HttpRequest<any>, options?: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.request(
    new HttpRequest(request.method, request.url, request.body, {
      headers: request.headers,
      responseType: request.responseType,
      ...options
    })
  );
}
```

This leads to the even more weird behavior, that now no matter what my options look like, I always only receive `{type: 0}` as response from the request.

What am I overseeing? I use Angular 5.1.1 and I am really a bit puzzled here right now.

So to give an explicit example, right now I receive the same response for those two HttpRequests:

```
{  
  "url":"http://127.0.0.1:8888/test",
  "body":{  
   "data":"testdata"
  },
  "reportProgress":false,
  "withCredentials":false,
  "responseType":"json",
  "method":"POST",
  "headers":{ some-headers ... }
}
```

and this request:

```
{  
  "url":"http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/pages",
  "body":{  
    "pageUrl":"http://localhost:1234/"
  },
  "reportProgress":true,
  "withCredentials":false,
  "responseType":"json",
  "method":"POST",
  "headers":{ some-headers ... }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a wrapper class rather than an [interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)? Also note that the `.clone` method is probably a better way to create a new request based on an existing one.

Comment: Because it's been a while that the wrapper has been written and there has not been time yet to rewrite it. I am aware of the `.clone()`-method, but wanted a generic approach, where I do not have to check for single properties in the option-object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issues. There were actually two things that were involved in the behavior described in the question.

First of all ... rtfm! https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

> This method [HttpClient.request()] can be called in one of two ways. Either an HttpRequest instance can be passed directly as the only parameter, or a method can be passed as the first parameter, a string URL as the second, and an options hash as the third.
>
> If a HttpRequest object is passed directly, an Observable of the raw HttpEvent stream will be returned.

This explains why my two request (both passed as `HttpRequest` returned `{type: 0}` from now on, regardless of the `reportProgress`-paramter being `true` or `false`.

Only receiving the SENT-event (`{type: 0}`) on the other hand was a missconfiguration of the backend itself.

Comment: Can you add more detail about how you solved the issue?

Comment: In [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request) you can find more details: *"The observe value determines the return type, according to what you are interested in observing"* **1)** An observe value of events returns an observable of the raw `HttpEvent` stream, including progress events by default. **2)** An observe value of response returns an observable of `HttpResponse<T>`, where the `T` parameter depends on the `responseType` and any optionally provided type parameter.
**3)** An observe value of body returns an observable of `<T>` with the same `T` body type.

Comment: what was the misconfig in the backend? do we need any special handling in the backend?

Answer (score 11):

along with {reportProgress: true} you would need to send {observe: 
'events'}

```
this.httpClient.post(environment.uploadDocument, file, { reportProgress: true, observe: 'events' })
.subcribe(data =>{
if (data['type'] === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
   console.log('loaded ', data['loaded'], '   total  -', data['total']);
   }
})
```

Comment: `observe: "events"` makes the file corrupt

Comment: I have been using the same. Works good for me. If you could share more details regarding you project.

Answer (score 6):

This method may help

```
public progress: number = 0;
public message: string = "";

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

onSubmit() {
    // replace with your request data
    const formModel = this.userForm.value;
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("upload", formModel.upload);

    const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', 'api/Upload', formData, {
        reportProgress: true,
    });

    this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe((event) => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        }
        else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            this.message = event.body.toString();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry, but this is just the first snippet you find when googling how to track upload progess with angular (which I already found: "I found several pages suggesting to use the reportProgress parameter"). The answer does not give any input on my actual question ...

Comment: @newnoise, it's what I'm currently using and it works; even if it is the first result in Google.

Answer (score 3):

After reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/54899930/1429439 I added the *observe: 'events'* parameter and started receiving the HttpEvents in my subscription.

Answer (score 2):

if You Are using service worker you have to send `ngsw-bypass` header.

example:-

```
file: File;

uploadProgress: number;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

uploadData(): void {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.file);


    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'ngsw-bypass': '' });

    this.http.post(`upload url`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events',
      headers
    }).subscribe(event => {

            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                this.uploadProgress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
            }
            else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
                console.log(event.body);
            }

        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return this.http.request('POST', api_enpoint , { body: body, headers: headers, reportProgress: true, withCredentials: true }).map(httpResponse => {
   console.log(httpResponse);
});
```

Instead of passing the httpRequest object, you need to pass the request in this fashion (works for both http as well for https)

Answer (score 0):

**Upload the formdata along with header details**

This snipet will help ou to upload formdata and while subscribe you can implement the progress bar as well

```
uploadMyImage(formData: any) {
    const httpOptions = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'boundary': 'something'
      });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/api/upload', formData, { reportProgress: true, observe: 'events', headers: httpOptions });
  }
```