# How to use reportProgress in HttpClient in Angular?

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular7

I am downloading file using `HTTP` `POST` method. I want to call another method to show download progress to end user until file download complete.
How to use `reportProgress` in `HttpClient` for this.

```
  downfile(file: any): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.post(this.url , app, {
      responseType: "blob", reportProgress: true, headers: new HttpHeaders(
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      )
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to use **`reportProgress: true`** to show some progress of any **`HTTP`** request. If you want to see **`all events, including the progress of transfers`** you need to use **`observe: 'events'`** option as well and return an **`Observable`** of type **`HttpEvent`**. Then you can catch all the **`events(DownloadProgress, Response..etc)`** in the component method.
**Find more details in [Angular Official Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events).**

```
  downfile(file: any): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{

    return this.http.post(this.url , app, {
      responseType: "blob", reportProgress: true, observe: "events", headers: new HttpHeaders(
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      )
    });
  }
```

**Then in component you can catch all the `events` as below.**

```
this.myService.downfile(file)
    .subscribe(event => {

        if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
            console.log("download progress");
        }
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            console.log("donwload completed");
        }
});
```

**Find [HttpEventTypes Here.](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEventType)**

Comment: how do I configure the package bytes amount for each part of the file?

Comment: @Sérgio S. Filho  could not get what you are asking

Comment: Hello! in order to send a file to the server in parts, the client app will break the file in some smaller amounts of bytes. I was looking for how to configure the size of each of these small packages of bytes. I think it could increase or decrease the visual feedback percentage precision. And maybe help to show a smoother loading feedback.

Comment: Does the server/backend need to be configured in a certain way? As in, return a stream or [report progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: @Jnr No dependency for the backend from this change.

Answer (score 3):

you will have to add HttpClientModule in your AppModule

you first need to build a request object by creating an instance of HttpRequest class and using reportProgress option.

For more information, please refer: 
https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-intro/