# Trouble getting progress and file when downloading a file in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

I have an Angular application where I just want to download a file.

Up until now, this was my code:

```
this.fileNavigationService.downloadFile(element).subscribe(result => {
    this.generateDownload(result);
});
```

And my service:

```
downloadFile(file: FileElement) {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/downloadFile', { params: file.name, responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

Now, I wanted to show the progression when I download a file. After looking up online, I came across something quite useful. My service now looks like this:

```
downloadFile(file: FileElement) {
    const req = new HttpRequest('GET', '/downloadFile?path=' + file.name, {
      reportProgress: true,
    });

    return this.http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% downloaded.`);
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('File is completely downloaded!');
      }
    });
}
```

I can clearly see in my console the progress, however, I have now 2 problems:

- My code never goes into the last `if` even though the download appears to reach 100%
- The code in my component is obviously broken on the subscribe method

  > Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.

But I can't seem to find a way to make this works so I can get the progression and my result file.

Do you have any idea or examples to help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: substitute `subscribe(...)` with a `.pipe( tap(...) )` to pass through the Observable

Comment: as for the "last if not firing" — its not clear, try outputting the `type` of each event. If you're really getting a `HttpResponse` — then you could also try duck-type checking it, e.g. `event.type === HttpEventType.Response`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research, I finally managed to solve my issue thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54899930).

This is now my service code:

```
downloadFile(file: FileElement) {
  return this.http.get(
    this.apiUrl + '/downloadFile', 
    { 
        params: file.name, 
        responseType: 'blob',
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events', 
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) 
    }
  );
}
```

And in my component:

```
this.fileNavigationService.downloadFile(element).subscribe(result => {
    if (result.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
      const percentDone = Math.round(100 * result.loaded / result.total);
      console.log(percentDone);
    }
    if (result.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
      this.generateDownload(result.body);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you don't need to define another content-type in the header