# Array of ZoneAwarePromise during downloading elements from Azure in Angular

Tags: angular, promise, azure-blob-storage, angular-promise

I am downloading files from Azure Blob storage via endpoint. For now I am waiting and downloading one by one in following part of my code.

```
for (let idx = 0; idx < blobArray.length ; idx++)
{
  downloadedFiles.push(await this.azureBlowService.downloadFile(containerName, blobArray[idx])) 
}
return downloadedFile
```

Download method in service

```
async downloadFile(containerName, fileName){
  let parameters = new HttpParams()
    .set("containerName", containerName)
    .set("fileName", fileName);

  let url = environment.baseUrl + "/api/v1/azure_blob/download_file";
  this.asyncResult = await this.http.get(url, {params: parameters, responseType: 'blob'}).toPromise()
  this.asyncResult.name = fileName;
  return this.asyncResult
}
```

When I remove await before `this.azureBlowService.donwloadFile...` I will get array of ZoneAwarePromises like this `[ZoneAwarePromise, ZoneAwarePromise, ZoneAwarePromise]` My assumption is that I would remove this await do the promises for all blow elements to allow them download in parallel process to make it faster and await for finishing all promises instead of not one by one. Now it is downloading really long especially if I have more than 100 elements. Is it possible? Would someone know how to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any advantage here in converting the promises to observables. I'd actually be easier to trigger all the requests in parallel if it is an observable.

1. Use `map` operator to append the `name` property to the response
2. Use `forkJoin` function to combine and trigger requests in parallel

Try the following

```js
downloadFile(containerName, fileName): Observable<any> {
  let parameters = new HttpParams()
    .set("containerName", containerName)
    .set("fileName", fileName);

  let url = environment.baseUrl + "/api/v1/azure_blob/download_file";
  return this.http.get(url, {params: parameters, responseType: 'blob'}).pipe(
    map((res: any) => ({ ...res, name: fileName }))   // <-- append `fileName` to `name` property
  );
}

forkJoin(
  blobArray.map(blob => this.downloadFile(containerName, blob))
).subscribe({
  next: response => {
    // output: array of response from invidual requests
    // statements that depend on `response`
  },
  error: error => {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I have two questions:
1. How to "await" for this? I need to wait for this Obvservable to be finished before I will go with my next stuff.
2. The response is not a array of blobs but the array of Objects. I am not sure if it is the same?

Comment: @horytnik: 1. You don't need to `await` this response. If the response needs to be forwarded elsewhere you only need to return the observable without the subscription and subscribe to it where the response is required. 2. If it's not an array of `blob` then the `responseType: 'blob'` isn't required in the HTTP request. You could remove it.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Changed a little bit return and now it works better than my previous solution. From 2.5 minutes of downloading I have less than 1.5 minutes :) 
I changed it to `return this.http.get(url, {params: parameters, responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response'}).pipe(map((result: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {result['body']["name"] = fileNamereturn result['body'];}) `
Because in your case it was not returning the blob type which was neccessary for me.

Comment: I have one more question. Is it somehow possible to log the progress of subscribing/donwloading blobs in this case?

Comment: @horytnik: I've not done it before but you could start referring here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55519765/6513921