# Javascript: What is reportProgress in Http Services?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, swagger-codegen

What does reportProgress do in Javascript, specifically we are using Angular Typescript. Trying to locate document information on this.

```
return this.httpClient.request<ProductResponse>('get',`${this.basePath}/api/Productcy/GetProductBNumber`,
    {
        params: queryParameters,
        withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
        headers: headers,
        observe: observe,
        reportProgress: reportProgress
    }
);
```

Background: Using Angular to call Net Core APIs, using Swagger Codegen IO Proxy Generator.

Comment: Did you consider reading the docs? This and the API docs both show up if you type `reportProgress` in the search bar: https://angular.io/guide/http#tracking-and-showing-request-progress

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use reportProgress in HttpClient in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896501/how-to-use-reportprogress-in-httpclient-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use reportProgress: true to show some progress of any HTTP request. If you want to see all events, including the progress of transfers you need to use observe: 'events' option as well and return an Observable of type HttpEvent. Then you can catch all the events(DownloadProgress, Response..etc) in the component method. Find more details see https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events