# Unable to set interval up to max 2 min or until condition met using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

here what my scenario is  i have 2 api's   **apiOne** and **apiTwo** and when ever i call the **apiOne** is should give response and if the response is success then i have to send this repsonse to **apiTwo** as param then **apiTwo**  will give another response in that i may get like  "created" ,"in_progress" . here the issue is

1. How can i call the **apitwo** using interval for every 3 seconds until i get the response as "in_progress" and if i didnt get the response as like above then i need to poll the **apiTwo** till max 2 min and cancel the call. if i get the response as **in_progress** then i need to stop the interval or max 2 min cancel the interval or subcription.
2. I already wrote the code in nested way but it is not efficient .

below is my code

```
 initiate() {
    this.showProgress = true;
    
    const data = {
      id: this.id,
      info: this.Values.info,
    };

    // First Api call
    
    this.userServ.start(data).subscribe(res => {
     
      this.Ids = res['Id'];
      if (this.Ids) {
      
      
      // Second Api call
      
        this.Service.getStatus(this.Ids).subscribe(resp => {

          if (resp) {
            
            this.Status = res['Status'];
            
            // if resp is In_Progress
            
            if (this.Status === 'In_Progress') {
              this.Start();
            } else {

            // if resp is not In_Progress then i get the response i am calling the api
            
              this.intervalTimer = interval(3000).subscribe(x => {

                this.Service.Status(this.Ids).subscribe(ress => {
                 
                  this.Status = ress['Status'];
                  if (this.Status === 'In_Progress') {
                    this.delayStart();
                    this.intervalTimer.unsubscribe();
                  }
                });
              });

            }
          }

        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }

    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }
```

Comment: I think making api calls after a set interval is a lot of overhead on the app and the network. Will this help you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896501/how-to-use-reportprogress-in-httpclient-in-angular

Comment: @ChetanBansal NO this is a different one my scenario is different

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using the below approach [See Code on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-km4tmz)

```
  id = 1;
  Values = { info: true };
  get data() { return { id: this.id,info: this.Values.info}}
  showProgressSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  showProgressAction$ = this.showProgressSubject$.asObservable();
  currentStatusSubject$ = new Subject<string>();
  currentStatus$ = this.currentStatusSubject$.asObservable()
  stoppedSubject$ = new Subject();
  stopped$ = this.stoppedSubject$.asObservable();
  startedSubject$ = new Subject();
  started$ = this.startedSubject$.asObservable();
  interval = 500; // Change to 3000 for 3s
  maxTrialTime = 6000;// Change to 120000 for 2min
  timer$ = timer(0, this.interval).pipe(
    tap((i) => {
      if(this.maxTrialTime/this.interval < i) { this.stoppedSubject$.next()}
    }),
    takeUntil(this.stopped$),
    repeatWhen(() => this.started$)
  )
  apiOneCall$ = this.userServ.start(this.data);
  apiTwoCall$ = this.apiOneCall$.pipe(
    switchMap(({Id}) => Id ? this.Service.getStatus(Id): throwError('No Id')),
    tap((res) => this.currentStatusSubject$.next(res)),
    tap(res => console.log({res})),
    tap((res) => {if(res === 'created') {this.stoppedSubject$.next()}})
  )
  trialCallsToApiTwo$ = this.timer$.pipe(mergeMap(() => this.apiTwoCall$))
```

In your Html you can use the async pipe

```
Show Progress : {{ showProgressAction$ | async }} <br>
Timer: {{ timer$ | async }}<br>

Response: {{ trialCallsToApiTwo$ | async }}<br>

<button (click)="startedSubject$.next()">Start</button><br>
<button (click)="stoppedSubject$.next()">Stop</button><br>
```

### Explanation

We begin by setting up the properties `id`, `Values` and `data` being a combination of the 2 values

```
 id = 1;
 Values = { info: true };
 get data() { return { id: this.id,info: this.Values.info}}
```

We then create a `Subject` to help with tracking of the progress of the operations. I am using BehaviorSubject to set the initial value of showing Progress to true.

We will use `currentStatus$` to store whether current state is 'in_progress' or 'created'

`stopped$` and `started` will control our observable stream.

You may have a look at the below post [What is the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)

```
showProgressSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
showProgressAction$ = this.showProgressSubject$.asObservable();
currentStatus$ = this.currentStatusSubject$.asObservable()
stoppedSubject$ = new Subject();
stopped$ = this.stoppedSubject$.asObservable();
startedSubject$ = new Subject();
started$ = this.startedSubject$.asObservable();
```

Next we define `interval = 500; // Change to 3000 for 3s` and `maxTrialTime = 6000;// Change to 120000 for 2min`

We then define a `timer$` observable using the `timer` operator. The operator is used to generate a stream of values at regular interval

We set the delay to `0` and the interval to `interval` property we had earlier created

We then `tap` into the observable stream. The `tap` operator allows us perform an operation without changing the observable stream

In our tap operator, we check whether the maximum time has been reached and if it has we call the next function on `stoppedSubject$`. We pipe our stream to `takeUntil(this.stopped$)` to stop the stream and `repeatWhen(() => this.started$)` to restart the stream

```
  timer$ = timer(0, this.interval).pipe(
    tap((i) => {
      if(this.maxTrialTime/this.interval < i) { this.stoppedSubject$.next()}
    }),
    takeUntil(this.stopped$),
    repeatWhen(() => this.started$)
  )
```

The Remaining part is to make a call to the apis
We will use `switchMap` to combine the two observables. `switchMap` will cancel any earlier request if a new request is made. If this is not your desired behaviour you may consider `exhaustMap` or the `mergeMap` operators

From the result of `apiOneCall$` if no id, we use the `throwError` operator to indicate an error otherwise we return a call to apiTwo

We tap into the result of `apiTwoCall$` and call the next function on `currentStatusSubject$` passing in the response. This sets the value of `currentStatus$` to the result of the response

The line `tap((res) => {if(res === 'created') {this.stoppedSubject$.next()}})` taps into the result of `apiTwoCall$` and if it is 'created' it stops the timer

```
apiOneCall$ = this.userServ.start(this.data);
apiTwoCall$ = this.apiOneCall$.pipe(
  switchMap(({Id}) => Id ? this.Service.getStatus(Id): throwError('No Id')),
  tap((res) => this.currentStatusSubject$.next(res)),
  tap(res => console.log({res})),
  tap((res) => {if(res === 'created') {this.stoppedSubject$.next()}}) 
)
```

Now we finally combine the `timer$` and `apiTwoCall$` with `mergeMap` operator `trialCallsToApiTwo$ = this.timer$.pipe(mergeMap(() => this.apiTwoCall$))`

In Our HTML we can then use the `async` pipe to avoid worrying about unsubscribing

```
{{ trialCallsToApiTwo$ | async }}
```

Comment: Maybe a little explaining, because you are bombarding the OP with observables.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof Okay , will update my answer with the explanation

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `expand` from rxjs, which will pass through the result of the source observable, but also let's you act according to the content of the result.

Also, avoid nesting calls to `subscribe` whenever possible. Consider this example code for reference:

```
this.userServ.start(data).pipe(
  // use switchMap to not have 'nested' subscribe-calls
  switchMap((result) => {
    if (result['Id']) {
      // if there is an ID, ask for the status
      return this.Service.getStatus(result['Id']).pipe(
        // use the expand operator to do additional processing, if necessary
        expand((response) => response['Status'] === 'In_Progress'
          // if the status is 'In_Progress', don't repeat the API call
          ? EMPTY
          // otherwise, re-run the API call
          : this.Service.getStatus(result['Id']).pipe(
            // don't re-run the query immediately, instead, wait for 3s
            delay(3000)
          )
        ),
        // Stop processing when a condition is met, in this case, 60s pass
        takeUntil(timer(60000).pipe(
          tap(() => {
            // handle the timeout here
          })
        ))
      );
    } else {
      // if there is no ID, complete the observable and do nothing
      return EMPTY;
    }
  }),
  /**
   * Since expand doesn't filter anything away, we don't want results that
   * don't have the status 'In_Progress' to go further down for processing
   */
  filter((response) => response['Status'] === 'In_Progress')
).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    this.Start();
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  }
);
```