# Typescript updating view with progressing

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I have this view that is just displaying a loader.gif and a message to the user. I would like to add some text of the progress something like processing 1 of 50 and so on. The ts class calls a data service layer and that is updating the data base and I would like to call back to the UI and in between each record.

View

```
<div class="modal-body" *ngIf="updateVersionItemsInProgress">
   <div *ngIf="updateVersionItemsInProgress">
      <img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" /><span>Updating templates...</span>
   </div>
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
      Processing {{currentitem}} of {{items.length}}
   </label>
</div>
```

ts file

```
private updateItems() {
  let versionKeys = this.items.map(i => i.VersionKey);
  this.updateVersionItemsInProgress = true;
        
  this.templatesManagementService.updateToNewVersion(versionKeys)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your data service layer is set up you could use the **`reportProgress: true`** flag to get some indicator of progress, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54899930/16309059. This will not give you individual record counts however.

Comment: What type of information of progress can I get from this?

Comment: When I look at the HttpEventType I don’t see anything I can use an I missing something?

Comment: use event.loaded and event.total see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsb8zj?file=src/app/app.component.ts