# Angular not displaying streamed data in UI using observable

Tags: angular, observable, streaming

I have python server which does server side streaming, i could see the request is successful, in browser i could see the data coming as stream for 10s. But in network tab response preview is coming only after all the data s being received.

I have used observable to handle the response. The success call for observable is being called only once.

But I want to display data as soon as its received no need to wait for entire data to display it.

How to achieve this ? displaying streamed data as and when its received

[image]
[image]
[image]

here data s streamed for 10s, but in network tab data is previewed only after 10 seconds so in angular observable success response also called after 10s. I have added an alert statement even that gets triggered once. I am expecting it to be called multiple time as and when data comes

[image]

Streamed response data. Each chunk is a json object

[image]

Comment: I don't see any stream, I only a single HTTP POST request that is expected to return single response. And in your case it seems to take around 10.06s to respond which is higher than ideal.

Comment: @MichaelD I have updated the question with response object.  In response you can see that each object is returned separated.

Comment: @user2900572 try like this `this.grpcResponse = [ ...devResponse ]`

Comment: When i receive the first response i want to show that record in table, when next response comes i want to show next response and so on. Between every response there a 0.5 seconds delay from server. But in UI data is coming after 10s not one by one. How to get data one by one in browser

Comment: This is interesting. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54896501/853678), which is about downloading a file, but I think the principle might be the same.
Alternatively, you might want to look at websockets instead